# Take Average Color of Screen - Windows 7 C/C++

Tags: windows, windows-7, colors, desktop, pixel

I'm trying to find the average pixel color of the entire screen or section of the screen in a C/C++ program. For example, say I wanted to find the average pixel color of the coordinate 0,0 to 50, 500?

My goal is to poll the whole screen, and not just one window the background.

If it's very difficult in C/C++, I suppose I could use Python.

Any suggestions for what I can use? Any example code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? (1) reading pixels from the screen, or (2) computing the average value of a group of pixels?

Comment: Reading the pixels. I'm not sure what I should use to get a pixel from the entire screen, rather than just a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GetDC(NULL)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921543.aspx) to get a HDC that refers to the entire screen. You can then use `BitBlt` or other pixel-moving function to get the pixels from the screen into a buffer that you can read from.

Comment: Seems like just what I'm looking for! Thanks Greg. And from here, any suggestions on how to go about calculating the average color from the pixel buffer?

Comment: The simplest way would be to take the average of each R, G, B channel and use that as the output. However, you may get a better result by using a different color space, such as HSV. I searched for "average color" here on SO and got a lot of related questions.